# Proper translation of " 倒页、脱页"？

Tags: translation

"凡购买XX出版社的图书，如有缺页、倒页、脱页者，本社发行部负责调换", does this translation "The house will be liable to replace book(s), should any missing, reversing and loosing pages be found in the books published by XX Publishing House" make any sense to you? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I think 倒页 means upside down pages. Check out this result from Baidu Image: [image: 倒页]

As you surmised, 脱页 refers to the pages falling out. Check out this result from Baidu Image:
[image: 脱页]

Note that the translation should probably have `loose pages` instead of `loosing pages`.

Comment: KEY http://www.cjkware.com/search?query=%E5%80%92%E9%A1%B5&option= tho - does translate 倒页 as  ◊ book pages out of order ---- although not equal to "reversing" - out of order would work

Comment: Thanks! Sweeper makes a good point! "upside down pages" might be more accurate as it is a situation of "out of order".

Comment: @Thea0408 Ringil wrote the exact same thing way before sweeper's post....

Comment: Out of order seems plausible as does page is on the wrong side: i.e. page order is 1 3 2 instead of 1 2 3

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense. The publisher would give you another copy of the book if there is any missing pages(缺页) and upside down pages (倒页). In the sentence, it also mentioned 脱页, which a bit different from 缺页, 脱页 means the page is not "connected" to the book and 缺页 means the page is literally gone, not even *in* the book.